# SML Syntax error, operator is not a function. I am very confused

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I am brand new to SML. Can some explain why line four is giving me this error? I have absolutely no clue why.

```
fun plus x y = x + y;
fun twice f x = f ( f ( x));
fun repeat n f x = if n = 0 then x else repeat (n-1) f (f(x));
fun times x y = repeat( x (plus( x y)) x);
```

```
- val plus = fn : int -> int -> int
val twice = fn : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a
val repeat = fn : int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a
stdIn:4.25-4.41 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: int
  in expression:
    (x (plus (x y))) x
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what @Nalin Ranjan said in his answer, a common issue with SML (or other ML family languages) syntax is understanding function application syntax.

Let's consider a very simple function named `f`:

```
fun f x = x + 1
```

This function takes a single argument `x` and transforms it into `x + 1`. The signature for this fucntion is `int -> int`. It takes an int and gives us back an int.

We can call it like so:

```
f 4
```

Functions in ML family languages can be said to only take one argument. If we want `f` to take two ints and add them together we have two ways to accomplish this. First, we can create a fucntion which takes one int and returns a function that takes another int and then adds them together.

```
fun f x = fn y => x + y
```

This function now has signature `int -> int -> int`. Add a pair of parentheses and it maybe makes more sense: `int -> (int -> int)`. It's a fucntion that takes an int and returns a function that takes an int and returns an int. SML gives us a more convenient way to write this.

```
fun f x y = x + y
```

Either way we define the function, we call it the same way:

```
f 4 5
```

At this point parentheses only serve to disambiguate order of operation. We could call `f` this way:

```
f(4)(5)
```

But if we do this, it doesn't work:

```
f(4 5)
```

Because `4 5` looks like function applications, but `4` isn't a function so we have a syntax error. A valid way to use parens would be something like `f (f 1 2) 6`.

This leads to the second way to get an SML function that takes multiple arguments. *We don't*.

Instead of creating a function that returns a function, we simply pass a *tuple* to a function.

```
fun f (x, y) = x + y
```

In this example `(x, y)` is a single tuple value and we've used pattern matching to give names to its two constituents values. The rules are exactly the same as the first method, but it *looks* a lot more like a lot of more mainstream languages. This style is also very prominent in the SML community (Ocaml, by contrast commonly uses the first method).

It's hard to say whether this is a good thing or if it just creates unnecessary confusion by its visual similarity.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at the definitions of every function successively that we are defining here:-

```
val plus = fn: int -> int -> int
val twice = fn: ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a
val repeat = fn: int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a
```

And the function definition with error is

```
fun times x y = repeat( x (plus( x y)) x);
```

Since `repeat` is the function being applied in the definition of `times`, let's look at the expression being supplied to `repeat` as its argument

```
repeat (x (plus (x y)) x)
```

Now as per the definition of `repeat`, it expects 3 parameters...first of which is of type int, second is of type function `('a -> 'a)`, and third is parametizred over `'a` which means value of any type. Now lets look at the sub-expression supplied to `repeat` in the definition of `times`, and which is

```
( x (plus( x y)) x)
```

This parenthesized expression most likely will get a treatment of a single value, the problem is it's type will not be an `int`. And so the type mismatch.. which the compiler is telling us about.

I can attempt to fix this, but not sure if that attempt will achieve you a functionally correct code. However, it goes like this...

```
fun times x y = repeat x (plus x) y;
```

And all is well with the compiler... afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. After further research I figured it out. But your help was awesome and much appreciated.